# change <f6> to swedish charactors and related ggplot geom_bar issues in R

Tags: r, string, geom-bar

I have 2 issues related to Swedish characters. I am fetching data directly from MS SQL database. 
1.could anyone gives me a hint how could i change the   back to Swedish characters in R?

I use write.csv write the data out to csv then copy and paste those string here to make the df as follow

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

c <- c("c","u","m","j","c","u","m","j","c","u","m","j")
city <- c("G<f6>teborg", "Ume<e5>", "Malm<f6>", "J<f6>nk<f6>ping","G<f6>teborg", "Ume<e5>", "Malm<f6>", "J<f6>nk<f6>ping","G<f6>teborg", "Ume<e5>", "Malm<f6>", "J<f6>nk<f6>ping")
priority <- c(1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,2,3,3,2)
n_cust <- sample(50:1000, 12, replace=T)
df <- data.frame(c,city,priority,n_cust)
```

should be ö and  is å

2. interesting enough. if i use the code as following:

> ```
> dpri %>% group_by(kommun, artikel_prioritet) %>% 
>   summarise(n_cust=n_distinct(kund_id),
>             sum_sales=sum(p_sum_adj_sale),
>             avg_margin=mean(pp_avg_margin),
>             avg_pec_sales=mean(p_pec_sales)) %>% 
>   arrange(desc(sum_sales)) %>% 
>   head(20)%>% 
>   ggplot(aes(x=reorder(kommun, sum_sales), y=sum_sales, 
>   fill=factor(artikel_prioritet))) +
>   geom_bar(stat='identity')+
>   coord_flip()+
>   scale_y_continuous(labels = comma)+
>   facet_grid(.~ factor(artikel_prioritet), scales = "free")+
>   theme(legend.position="none")
> ```

i got this error:
Error in grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  : 
  invalid input 'Göteborg' in 'utf8towcs'

if I first put this head(20) into a variable ci. then use ggplot to plot ci

> ggplot(ci,aes(x=reorder(kommun, sum_sales), y=sum_sales,
>   fill=factor(artikel_prioritet))) +   geom_bar(stat='identity')+
>   coord_flip()+   scale_y_continuous(labels = comma)+   facet_grid(.~
>   factor(artikel_prioritet), scales = "free")+
>   theme(legend.position="none")

I have bar chart without any city legend. 
then I print out ci, I got pic as follow:
[image]

then, I write the head(20) to a csv 'cityname.csv' then read.csv back to R
use the same code to do the bar chart

> ci <- read.csv("cityname.csv")
>
> ggplot(ci,aes(x=reorder(kommun, sum_sales), y=sum_sales,
>   fill=factor(artikel_prioritet))) +   geom_bar(stat='identity')+
>   coord_flip()+   scale_y_continuous(labels = comma)+   facet_grid(.~
>   factor(artikel_prioritet), scales = "free")+
>   theme(legend.position="none")

I got the pic as follow:
[image]

we can see legends this time but see ,  this time. 
hope get some suggestions how could i fix the strings in Swedish and wondering suggestion is there any other way without write.csv and then read again still can get the bar chart fixed?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your issue is that R doesn't know how to interpret your character encoding. Try `\u` notation instead of `<>`, which denotes UTF-8 encoding in R

```
> city <- c("G\u00f6teborg", "Ume\u00e5", "Malm\u00f6", "J\u00f6nk\u00f6ping","G\u00f6teborg", "Ume\u00e5", "Malm\u00f6", "J\u00f6nk\u00f6ping","G\u00f6teborg", "Ume\u00f6", "Malm\u00f6", "J\u00f6nk\u00f6ping")
> Encoding(city)
 [1] "UTF-8" "UTF-8" "UTF-8" "UTF-8" "UTF-8" "UTF-8" "UTF-8" "UTF-8" "UTF-8" "UTF-8" "UTF-8" "UTF-8"
> head(city)
[1] "Göteborg"  "Umeå"      "Malmö"     "Jönköping" "Göteborg"  "Umeå"
```

EDIT:
You asked a good follow up question about how to make this replacement programmatically. I have provided a solution for that as well below, using the `tidyverse` packages `dplyr` and `stringr`

```r
> city <- c("G<f6>teborg", "Ume<e5>", "Malm<f6>", "J<f6>nk<f6>ping","G<f6>teborg", "Ume<e5>", "Malm<f6>", "J<f6>nk<f6>ping","G<f6>teborg", "Ume<f6>", "Malm<f6>", "J<f6>nk<f6>ping")
> city_df <- as.data.frame(city)

> special_character_replacements <- c("<f6>" = "\\u00f6", "<e5>" = "\\u00e5")
> city_df %>% 
    dplyr::mutate(city_fixed = 
        stringr::str_replace_all(city, special_character_replacements))

              city city_fixed
1      G<f6>teborg   Göteborg
2          Ume<e5>       Umeå
3         Malm<f6>      Malmö
4  J<f6>nk<f6>ping  Jönköping
5      G<f6>teborg   Göteborg
6          Ume<e5>       Umeå
7         Malm<f6>      Malmö
8  J<f6>nk<f6>ping  Jönköping
9      G<f6>teborg   Göteborg
10         Ume<f6>       Umeö
11        Malm<f6>      Malmö
12 J<f6>nk<f6>ping  Jönköping
```

Comment: thank you for the comment but sorry for asking, how can I change <> to \u format at the first place? any recommendation?

Comment: Great question, I appended a solution to my answer. Please mark this as accepted if  it helps you :-)

Comment: Thank you so much. if you can also give me suggestion how could I find out "<f6>" = "\\u00f6" . i think I have 4 different characters here. Now only covered two of them  "<f6>" &"<e5>".  if I google what key words do you suggest me to use? thank you

Comment: Whichever character like `<f6>` appear in your data, you can remove the `<>` characters, and then add `\u00` to the beginning. 
So `<f6>` becomes `\u00f6`, `<e5>` becomes `\u00e5`, and a character (that I made up) called `<a1>` would become `\u00a1`

Comment: Thank you so  much!